# How to use co library in loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my sample code.

```
response.results.forEach((val, index) => {
    mu.co(function*() {
        uIds[index].response = val
        uIds[index].dateOnly = _.date
        uIds[index].count    = 1
        yield _.insertUserIdWiseResponse(uIds[index])
    })
})
```

I want to make it synchronized.

Comment: I want to make insertUserIdWiseResponse()  this function synchronized.

Comment: insertUserIdWiseResponse() - it contains co routine in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write co ( mu.co(function*() {) statement outside the loop, it should work. 
But you have to use it with (for(of) loop)

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to do this is:

```
return mu.co(function*() {
    for (let [index, val] of response.results.entries()) {
        uIds[index].response = val
        uIds[index].dateOnly = _.date
        uIds[index].count    = 1
        yield notiResponse.upsert(uIds[index], notiResponse)
     }
})
```